# Input text on browser popup using nightwatch js

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

I want to write test script using nightwatch.js and selenium for a web application created using ruby. When the application launches, it asks the user to put username and password in a browser input dialog (a popup window with username and password text field). 
Is there any way I can send or enter text into the text fields using nightwatch.js?

Answer (score 1):

if it's a **popin**, you can basically use the `setValue` function:

```
// send some simple text to an input
this.demoTest = function (browser) {
  browser.setValue('#yourInputId', 'nightwatch');
};
```

API doc:http://nightwatchjs.org/api#setValue

---

If it's an "oldschool" **popup** (*window.open(...)* in javascript), you should use the `switchWindow` function before:

```
this.demoTest = function (browser) {
    browser.window_handles(function(result) {
        var handle = result.value[0];
        browser.switchWindow(handle);
        browser.setValue('#yourInputId', 'nightwatch');
    });
};
```

API doc: http://nightwatchjs.org/api#switchWindow

Comment: Can you give me a sample? 
module.exports = {
  'Demo test Google' : function (client) {
    client
      .url('http://localhost')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .setValue('username', 'testuser')
      .setValue('{TAB}')
      .setValue('password', 'testpass')
      .end();
  }
};

Comment: I need to enter username first then move to next text box password. I have used tab to move to next text box