# Use Window_handles to click button in location pop-up, with nightwatch

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, nightwatch.js, window-handles

I have a test in nightwatch for a function that requires you to share your location in order to show some results. Everytime i interact with that button, the geoiplocation default pop-up of the browser shows up and i need to interact with it (accept or dismiss it) in order to move on with the test.

In order to do this, i have tried `acceptAlert` mentioned in the Nightwatch api documentation, with no success. I read in several places that in this case you can use the command to switch to the new window, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156332/input-text-on-browser-popup-using-nightwatch-js) :

```
browser.window_handles(function(result) {
    var handle = result.value[0];
    browser.switchWindow(handle);
});
```

My problem is, how do i click that button, when i cannot view source of that pop-up to get the html for it? Or is there other way i can dismiss it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, in the end, i've got this answer from [github](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/935), which says that you cannot do that, but you can set your browser to not ask for approval anymore.
not very satisfying but...there you go, a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this syntax.
It may work:

```
browser.window_handles(function(result) {
    var handle = result.value[0];
    this.switchWindow(handle);
    this.useXpath(); or this.useCss()
    this.click("locator path")
});
```

Comment: the locator path means.. some element's path withing the pop-up? I'm afraid that's exactly the problem, that when i right-click it, nothing happens, i cannot see te html of that pop-up anywhere, therefore i cannot use and xpath or css selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  browser
           .click('@buttonPopup')
           .acceptAlert();
```

In case you are using a page-object ,it would be :

```
  pageObject.click('@buttonPopup',function(){
              browser.acceptAlert();           
      })
```

window_handles method will handle 'tab' instead of pop-up.

PS:Remember this,phantomjs wont work with acceptAlert/dismissAlert the pop-up.